# Sitemap Page build from Menu?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, menus, sitemap

Is there a plugin available that creates a sitemap from the default menu, e.g. as shortcode or requestbale URI?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? 
"This plugin generates a customizable sitemap which you can add to any page on your site using a simple shortcode."
[Atlas HTML Sitemap Generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/atlas-html-sitemap-generator/)

Comment: It doesn't for the menu, but looks nice as well. However I need this for the menu ...

Answer (score 2):

[WP Realtime Sitemap](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-realtime-sitemap/) includes the menu items in the sitemap.